# WSO2 EI - disable Random ports on startup

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

that is the question, how can I disable the dynamic ports that initialize the "integrator.sh", I need to disable or fix it by a requirement of the infrastructure people.
Thanks a lot!

[wso2-ei documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHXoE.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it in the following way. In the file integrator.sh comment the line
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote \

with that it does not generate random ports

Answer (score 1):

Actually u can change default ports via carbon.xml ($EI_Home/conf/carbon.xml).

You have to set 0 property as u want. Default port is 9443 for management console and it will change according to given offset.

If you give offset as 10, port will be 9453 for management console. And other ports also change accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, but I mean the other ports that randomly raises, and that are pointed out in the wso2-ei documentation when initializing the server. [Attach the wso2-ei documentation in original post]